# Evenly Space a list in an UIAlertview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

So I have a list of highscores that I display at the end of a game in a `UIAlertView` along with the users own score.

[image]

I was wondering whether there was a way to format this text so that it would appear in a nicely formatted list with even spacing for the different names and times or if I will have to create my own interface instead of using the `UIAlertView`.

EDIT: code for `UIAlertView`

```
UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Time: %.2f seconds.\n\n1. %@    %@\n2. %@    %@\n3. %@    %@\n4. %@    %@\n5. %@    %@",currentTime,[array objectAtIndex:0],[scoreArray objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1],[scoreArray objectAtIndex:1],[array objectAtIndex:2],[scoreArray objectAtIndex:2],[array objectAtIndex:3],[scoreArray objectAtIndex:3],[array objectAtIndex:4],[scoreArray objectAtIndex:4] ] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Main Menu",@"Play Again", nil];
```

Both the arrays are taken from `NSUserDefaults`

EDIT 2: Also, name is limited to 10 characters

Comment: Can you put the code of how you are creating that component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will need some string manipulation and formatting by adding tabs and space, my opinion is to build your own view to represent your custom information

Answer (score 2):

Try using \t and %  .2f That should help.

you could calculate how much space you need biased on the length of the name and use that as a separate sting between the names and such. It seems complicated but should work.

Comment: The scoreboard times are actually strings taken from the array.

Comment: Tried using the \t but doesn't work because depending on the name length I would have to put more or less tabs in

Comment: still no luck as the different letters are different widths probably just will create my own view. thanks